# Variance of the dot product of a random binary vector and a vector of constants

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $ q \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and Z a random binary vector s.t. the sum of its elements is n. 
The variance of the statistic $Z\cdot q = \sum^N _{i=1} Z_i q_i$ should be $ \frac{N-n}{N-1} \times n \times \frac{\sum ^N _{i=1} (q_i -\bar q)^2}{N} $,  however I don't understand how to achieve this equality.
What I do know is that

1. $E[Z\cdot q] = n\bar q$
2. $P[Z_i =1, Z_j =1] = \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)} $

I also managed to reach this: $ Z \cdot q = \sum ^ N _ {i=1} (q_i - \bar q)^2 \frac{n-1}{N^2} + \sum^N _{j=1} \sum^N _{k=1, k \neq j} (q_j - \bar q)(q_k - \bar q) \frac{n}{N}(\frac{n-1}{N-1} - \frac{n}{N}) $
but i don't know how to further simplify this expression. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Z_i\in\{0,1\}$, observe that $Z_i^2=1$ so that $\mathbb E(Z_i)^2=n/N$. Moreover, when $i\not=j$ we have 
$$
\mathbb EZ_iZ_j=\mathbb P(Z_i=Z_j=1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E(Z\cdot q)^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^Nq_iq_j\mathbb EZ_iZ_j=\frac{n}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2+\frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}\sum_{i\not=j}q_iq_j,\qquad \textrm{Var}(Z\cdot q)=\mathbb E(Z\cdot q)^2-(n\bar q)^2.
$$
To show that this matches your expression requires just a little algebra, the probability is finished.

First let's define some notation:
$$
\bar{q}:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^Nq_i}{N},\qquad S:=\sum_{i=1}^Nq_i^2.
$$

Recognizing that $\sum_{i\not=j}q_iq_j=(N\bar{q})^2-S$, we obtain that
$$
\mathbb E(Z\cdot q)^2=\frac{n}{N}\left[S+\frac{n-1}{N-1}\Bigl((N\bar{q})^2-S\Bigr)\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{n}{N(N-1)}\left[(N-n)S+(n-1)N^2\bar{q}^2\right].
$$
Substituting in the expression for $\textrm{Var}(Z\cdot q)$ obtained previously, we obtain that
$$
\textrm{Var}(Z\cdot q)=\frac{n}{N(N-1)}\left[(N-n)S+\bigl((n-1)N^2-nN(N-1)\bigr)\bar{q}^2\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{n(N-n)}{N(N-1)}\left[S-N\bar{q}^2\right].
$$
On the other hand, observe that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N(q_i-\bar{q})^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(q_i^2-2q_i\bar{q}+\bar{q}^2)=S-N\bar{q}^2.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\textrm{Var}(Z\cdot q)=\frac{n(N-n)}{N(N-1)}\sum_{i=1}^N(q_i-\bar{q})^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Just to make clear, when you write $E(Z\cdot q)^2$ you mean $ E[(Z\cdot q)^2] $, right?

Comment: yes, if I meant the latter I would write $(\mathbb EZ\cdot q)^2$ (this notation is standard...)

Comment: Cool. Thanks again